# How does type declaration work for function parameters?

Tags: javascript, typescript

below is the code:

```
interface Person { name: string };

const people = ['alice', 'bob', 'jan'].map(name => ({name}))   
// { name: string; }[]... but we want Person[]

const people = ['alice', 'bob', 'jan'].map(name => {
   const person: Person = {name};  // extra noise, need a better approach
   return person
});   // type is Person[]
```

so it can also be written as:

```
const people = ['alice', 'bob', 'jan'].map(
   (name): Person => ({ name })
); // Type is Person[]
```

I don't understand why `(name): Person` can be compiled, isn't that `name` is originally `string` type, how can it be declared to `Person` type? obviously you can't do:

```
let p: Person = "Alice";  // compile error, Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'Person'
```

Comment: Person you typed is not the type of the parameter 'name' but the return type. You confused (name: Person) => ({ name })  with it.

Comment: It means `function (name:string) => {} returns a Person`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's `(name): Person => …`, where `Person` specifies the return type of the arrow function. It does not declare the type of the parameter, which would have been `(name: Person) => …` (with inferred return type) or `(name: Person): … => …` (explicitly typed).

Btw, you can also use the generic type parameter of `map` for this:

```
const people = ['alice', 'bob', 'jan'].map<Person>(name => ({ name }));
```